# mapping enter key to newline and tab in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Whenever I
press the enter key, indicating an end of paragraph, vim should
automatically insert another new line, and insert a tab space in the next
line.  All this is to denote that I am ready to type the next paragraph.

Comment: Can't you just use `:set autoindent`

Comment: its doesnot work with the plugin i am developing///

Comment: i am writing for text file editing and managing//

Comment: if i add this line   :imap <CR>  <CR><Tab>  it behaves abnormaly

Comment: I strongly advise that it would be better to configure your plugin to work with `autoindent` rather than adding ad hoc imaps to achieve this. As a user I wouldn't be very happy with a plugin that redefined `<CR>` behind my back.

Comment: can you please extend your suggestions with explanation me means with your code...

Comment: No explanations needed, I think. Just let your users do `<cr>` and get the result they expect.

Comment: In what way does `autoindent` not work with your plugin? I suggest asking a new question to solve that problem, as we can't really give any more suggestions without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments saying that this is not a good idea to do, but the following works for me:

```
inoremap <buffer> <cr> <cr><cr><tab>
```

Comment: its actually can not give what i mentioned. it give me simultaneous tab with increment by 1 tab...but i have required only one tab after i press enter key everytime