# How to imap <Space> in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am writing a vim script which may need to map the  key to trigger a function, but it looks like whatever I write in the imap command, the mapping is not worked.

For testing purpose , I set map the  to  like:

```
imap <Space> <Esc>
```

So I should escape from the insert mode when I press a space.But it seems not working... Is it possible to imap  in vim? If not, I will find another way to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's so strange to answer my own question , but I found a solution after all. [mapping-enter-key-in-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834346/mapping-enter-key-to-newline-and-tab-in-vim?rq=1) In this question, the answer is

```
inoremap <buffer> <Space> <esc>
```

Another problem is that AutoPairs is overriding  setting.... So my setting is not working.

Comment: Did you tried putting `:au BufEnter *.* :imap <buffer> <space> <ESC>` in vimrc file?? This may override auto-pairs